# what is functions for this DNA to solve this problems python

Tags: python

[H6-4] (gene.py) Write a program that reads a string from the user.  This string represents a DNA molecule as a sequence of letters A, C, G, and T, each letter representing a different base. Then determine whether it represents a potential gene, if it satisfies the following 4-part codon criteria:

•   It begins with the start codon ATG.
•   Its length is a multiple of 3.
•   It ends with one of the stop codons TAG, TAA, or TGA.
•   It has no intervening stop codons, anywhere in the codon sequence between the first and last codons.

Do so by defining a Boolean function is_gene(dna) that returns True when dna is valid DNA and it satisfies each of the codon criteria.

Also define a Boolean function is_valid_DNA(seq) that returns True if each character in seq is one of A, C, G, or T. Otherwise return False.

Then complete your program: use your is_valid_DNA(seq) function to validate the input string seq's contents, printing Not valid DNA if it contains any characters other than one of A, C, G, and T. Otherwise, check it via your is_gene() function and print Is potential gene if it satisfies the previous 4-part codon criteria, and Is NOT potential gene otherwise.

Finally, if the input string is not valid DNA or violates the 4-part codon criteria, print out some kind of diagnostic information that describes details on why it's not valid.  This information might describe why the contents are invalid DNA, such as which bases are illegal and at what sequence position they occur. For the 4-part codon criteria, it might be a description such as "Doesn't start with ATG" or "Length isn't a multiple of 3", and so forth. I will award up to 1 point of Extra Credit for diagnostic output that is so detailed and nicely formatted.

Comment: It looks like you're asking for the complete solution to an assignment. This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You'll have to try to code something on your own first, then when you get stuck on your own attempt, come back here with a [sample of the work you've done so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to solve the problem so that others can help you.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question here, so i didn't know the real format, I'm sorry guys and i will add some code soon to show where i stuck with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following two functions. A string can be used as a list or a set. These two concepts come in handy for checking the conditions you are required to fullfill

```
def is_valid_DNA(dna):
    if len(set(dna) - {'A','C','G','T'}) == 0: return True
    return False

def is_gene(dna):
    if dna[0:3] != 'ATG': 
        print('Invalid start')
        return False
    if len(dna) % 3 != 0: 
        print('Invalid length')
        return False
    if dna[-3::] not in ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']:
        print('Invalid end')
        return False
    for i in range(len(dna)-3):
        if dna[i:i+3] in ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']: 
            print('Invalid inner sequence')
            return False
    return True

dna = input()

if not is_valid_DNA(dna): print('Not valid DNA')
else:
    if is_gene(dna): print('Vaid DNA sequence!')
    else: print('Invalid DNA sequence.')
```